# Ubuntu 18.04.4 + chrome + Xvfb - segmentation-fault after recent update

Tags: segmentation-fault

I'm experiencing segfault while trying to run Chrome (chrome-driver) on Xvfb on the newest 18.04.4:

```
kernel: [4477762.555614] chrome[9285]: segfault at ffffd9d5e7f40996 ip 00007f36b211f2dd sp 00007ffdf3ddb760 error 5 in libGLX_mesa.so.0.0.0[7f36b20dc000+73000]
```

The command I execute is the following:

```
DISPLAY=:99 /usr/bin/google-chrome https://google.com
```

It worked well until the following updates have been installed on 7th of Jan, 2020:

```
2020-02-07 06:20:40 upgrade libglapi-mesa:amd64 19.0.8-0ubuntu0~18.04.3 19.2.8-0ubuntu0~18.04.2
2020-02-07 06:20:40 status half-configured libglapi-mesa:amd64 19.0.8-0ubuntu0~18.04.3
2020-02-07 06:20:40 status unpacked libglapi-mesa:amd64 19.0.8-0ubuntu0~18.04.3
2020-02-07 06:20:40 status half-installed libglapi-mesa:amd64 19.0.8-0ubuntu0~18.04.3
2020-02-07 06:20:40 status half-installed libglapi-mesa:amd64 19.0.8-0ubuntu0~18.04.3
2020-02-07 06:20:40 status unpacked libglapi-mesa:amd64 19.2.8-0ubuntu0~18.04.2
2020-02-07 06:20:40 status unpacked libglapi-mesa:amd64 19.2.8-0ubuntu0~18.04.2
2020-02-07 06:20:40 startup packages configure
2020-02-07 06:20:40 configure libglapi-mesa:amd64 19.2.8-0ubuntu0~18.04.2 <none>
2020-02-07 06:20:40 status unpacked libglapi-mesa:amd64 19.2.8-0ubuntu0~18.04.2
2020-02-07 06:20:40 status half-configured libglapi-mesa:amd64 19.2.8-0ubuntu0~18.04.2
2020-02-07 06:20:40 status installed libglapi-mesa:amd64 19.2.8-0ubuntu0~18.04.2
2020-02-07 06:20:40 configure libglx-mesa0:amd64 19.2.8-0ubuntu0~18.04.2 <none>
2020-02-07 06:20:40 status unpacked libglx-mesa0:amd64 19.2.8-0ubuntu0~18.04.2
2020-02-07 06:20:40 status half-configured libglx-mesa0:amd64 19.2.8-0ubuntu0~18.04.2
2020-02-07 06:20:40 status installed libglx-mesa0:amd64 19.2.8-0ubuntu0~18.04.2
2020-02-07 06:20:40 trigproc libc-bin:amd64 2.27-3ubuntu1 <none>
2020-02-07 06:20:40 status half-configured libc-bin:amd64 2.27-3ubuntu1
2020-02-07 06:20:40 status installed libc-bin:amd64 2.27-3ubuntu1
```

Chrome version is: 80.0.3987.87

I tried to find if anyone had similar segfault related to the latest update but I haven't anything.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, and changing the DPI / Resolution in my Xvfb config solved the issue:

`Xvfb -screen 0 1280x800x24 -ac -dpi 96 +extension RANDR :99`

Hope this help.